# Перехват оконной процедуры

Tags: winapi, delphi

Здравствуйте. Возникла необходимость перехватывать оконную процедуру в приложениях типа браузера, Direct 3D игрушек и подобного. Моих познаний не хватает, поэтому прошу помощи.
Вот как видится мне перехват оконной функции:

Ставлю перехват

```
DeffWndProc := SetWindowLong(FindWindow(nil, 'заголовок нашего окошка'), GWL_WNDPROC, longint(@NewWndProc));
```

где `DeffWndProc: longword;`

перенаправляю на свой обработчик, который выглядит вот так:

```
function NewWndProc(const AHandle: THandle; const AMsg: longword;
const AwParam, AlParam: longint): longint; stdcall;
begin

   if AMsg = WM_ACTIVATE then
   begin
   Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('ACTIVATE');         // записываю в мемо
   end;

   if AMsg = WM_ACTIVATEAPP then
   begin
   Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('ACTIVATEAPP');      // записываю в мемо
   end;

result := CallWindowProc(pointer(DeffWndProc), AHandle, AMsg, AwParam, AlParam);   // вызываю оригинальную функцию
end;
```

Попробовал перехватить оконную функцию в своих приложениях - всё работает. Пытаюсь перехватить, например, в блокноте - не работает(
Что не так?

Comment: shurik, пробовал инжектить длл с таким перехватом в процесс блокнота - результат тоже нулевой

Comment: а какие именно события вам нужны ?

Завтра попытаюсь сделать пример.

Comment: shurik, спасибо, было бы замечательно. Для начала WM_ACTIVATE и WM_ACTIVATEAPP.
Вообще мне нужно сделать так, чтобы окно не знало, что оно неактивно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ммм, этот код должен быть как минимум в длл, и блокнот должен подгружать эту длл, например, поставить хук. В общем-то я думаю, что хука вам как раз хватит.

**upd:**

Создаём библиотеку:

```
library M_Hook;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils,
  dialogs;

const
 cMMFileName = 'Shell-hook_{E896D15B-DD63-4BC8-86F4-E0BF6A5573B6}';

type
 PGlobalData = ^TGlobalData;
 TGlobalData = packed record
   HookProcessId: DWORD;
   ShellHookHandle : HHOOK;
   WindowHandle: THandle;
   idMsg_Shell: LongWord;
 end;

 type
  PDataInfo = ^TDataInfo;
  TDataInfo = packed record
  nCode  : Integer;
  WParam : Integer;
  LParam : Integer;
 end;

Const
 XX_Ready = 1;
var
 GlobalData: PGlobalData ;
 MapHandle: THandle;
 OldWndProc : LongWord;
 WndHandle : THandle = 0;

function NewWndProc(const AHandle: THandle; const AMsg: longword;
  const AwParam, AlParam: longint): longint; stdcall;
  var
    F : file;
begin

  if (AMsg = WM_ACTIVATE) then
  begin
    //MessageBox(0, 'notepad activated', '', 0);
  end;
  result := CallWindowProc(Pointer(OldWndProc), AHandle, AMsg, AwParam, AlParam);
end;

function DeleteHook(CheckProcess: boolean): boolean;
begin
 Result := false;
 if GlobalData <> nil then
   with GlobalData^ do
    begin

     if ShellHookHandle<>0 then
       if (not CheckProcess) or (GetCurrentProcessId = HookProcessId) then
         begin
           Result := UnHookWindowsHookEx(ShellHookHandle) ;
           if Result then
             ShellHookHandle := 0;
         end;
    end;
end;

function RemoveHook: boolean; stdcall;
begin
 Result := DeleteHook(True);
end;

function ShellProc(nCode: integer; wParam: LongWord;
   lParam: LongWord): integer; stdcall;
 Var
  DI : PDataInfo;
  p : array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
 Result := 0;
 with GlobalData^ do
  Begin
    if IsWindow(WindowHandle) then
     Begin
      Case nCode Of
        HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED   : Begin
                                  PostMessage(WindowHandle, idMsg_Shell, wParam, Lparam);
                                  WndHandle := wParam;
                                  GetWindowText(wParam, p, MAX_PATH);
                                  //MessageBox(0,p, '', MB_OK);
                                  if Pos('зымянный', p) <> 0 then
                                  begin
                                    OldWndProc := SetWindowLong(wParam, GWL_WNDPROC, longint(@NewWndProc));
                                  end;

                                 End;
        HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED : Begin
                                  PostMessage(WindowHandle, idMsg_Shell+1, wParam, Lparam);
                                 End;
        HSHELL_LANGUAGE        : Begin
                                  PostMessage(WindowHandle, idMsg_Shell+2, wParam, Lparam);
                                 End;
        HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED : Begin
                                  PostMessage(WindowHandle, idMsg_Shell+3, wParam, Lparam);
                                 End;
//       Else DeleteHook(False);
     end;
      CallNextHookEx(ShellHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
     End  Else DeleteHook(False);
   End;
end;

function SetShellHook(CallbackWindow: THandle;
   idCallBackMessageS: LongWord): boolean; stdcall;
begin
 Result := false;
 if GlobalData <> nil then
   with GlobalData^ do
    Begin
      if ( ShellHookHandle = 0 ) then
       begin
         ShellHookHandle := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, @ShellProc, HInstance, 0);
         Result := ShellHookHandle <> 0;
         if Result then
          Begin
           idMsg_Shell :=  idCallBackMessageS ;
           WindowHandle := CallbackWindow;
          end;
       end;
      end;
end;

procedure OpenSharedData;
var
 Size: integer;
begin
 Size := SizeOf(TGlobalData);
 MapHandle := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE,
     0, Size, cMMFileName);
 if MapHandle = 0 then exit;
 GlobalData := MapViewOfFile(MapHandle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, Size);
end;

procedure CloseSharedData;
begin
 UnmapViewOfFile(GlobalData);
 CloseHandle(MapHandle);
end;

procedure DLLEntryProc(dwReason: DWord);
begin
 case dwReason of
   DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: OpenSharedData;
   DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
     begin
       if WndHandle > 0 then
         SetWindowLong(WndHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, longint(@OldWndProc));
       RemoveHook ;
       CloseSharedData;

     end;
 end;
end;

exports
 SetShellHook, RemoveHook;

begin
 DLLProc := @DLLEntryProc;
 DLLEntryProc(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

Ну  и управляющая программа:

```
unit main_frm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, MMSystem;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public
    Procedure ShellMessage (var mes : TMessage);message WM_User+3;
    Procedure ShellMessageDestroyW (var mes : TMessage);message WM_User+4;
    Procedure ShellMessageLang (var mes : TMessage);message WM_User+5;
    Procedure ShellMessageAct (var mes : TMessage);message WM_User+6;

    Function SH_GetWindowText(T:THandle):String;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

function RemoveHook: boolean; external 'm_hook.dll';
function SetShellHook(CallbackWindow: THandle;
   idCallBackMessageS: LongWord): boolean; stdcall;  external 'm_hook.dll';

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 RemoveHook;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Memo1.Clear;
 SetShellHook(Handle, WM_USER+3);
end;

procedure TForm1.ShellMessage(var mes: TMessage);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Window created - : '+IntToStr(mes.WParam)+'  '+SH_GetWindowText(mes.WParam));
end;

procedure TForm1.ShellMessageAct(var mes: TMessage);
begin
 Memo1.Lines.Add('Window Activated - : '+Format('W:%d  L:%d',[mes.WParam, mes.LParam])+'  '+SH_GetWindowText(mes.WParam));

end;

procedure TForm1.ShellMessageDestroyW(var mes: TMessage);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Window destroyed - : '+IntToStr(mes.WParam)+'  '+SH_GetWindowText(mes.WParam));
end;

procedure TForm1.ShellMessageLang(var mes: TMessage);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Keyboard Layout Change  - : '+IntToStr(mes.WParam)+'  '+SH_GetWindowText(mes.LParam));
end;

function TForm1.SH_GetWindowText(T: THandle): String;
 Var
  A:Array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  GetWindowText(T,A,Max_Path);
  Result := A;
end;

end.
```

Нашел у себя в закромах, и немного дописал интересующий вас момент. Код писался лет 5 назад, так что за качество не обезсудьте.

В общим в чем суть. Библиотека инжектится в адрессное пространство каждого процесса. И когда создается нужное нам окно:

```
if Pos('зымянный', p) <> 0 then
begin
    OldWndProc := SetWindowLong(wParam, GWL_WNDPROC, longint(@NewWndProc));
end;
```

(тестил на блокноте, по умолчанию у него титл "Безымянный")
мы переопределяем оконную процедуру. Обратите внимание, что оконная процедура подменяется во время создания приложения. Т.е если интересующее нас приложение запущенно позже нашей программы - то ничего не произойдет.

Управляющая программа ведет лог.

Comment: обновил ответ